# What is this question asking about different exercise strategies opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I asked a question on exercise strategies (see question below). Specifically, I presented three strategies to exercise. The question got closed on the grounds that it is opinion-based. In the comment, one close voter indicates that he cast the close vote because all strategies are pretty much equivalent. Shouldn't the question be left open with an answer simply saying all strategies are pretty much the same (regardless of anyone's opinion)?

---

> [Arm exercises: when to alternate
>   arms?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/31648/3806)
>
> I need to do three arm exercises A, B, and C. For each exercise, I
>   perform 2 series of 10 repetitions. I can only work with one arm at a
>   time. Which of the following sequence is preferable to maximize muscle
>   gain and minimize the risk of injury?
>
> - Do all exercises A, B, and C with left arm. Then, do all exercises A, B, and C with the right arm.
> - Alternate arm between each exercise, i.e.: Do the two series of exercise A with the left arm. Then, do two series of exercise A with
>     the right arm. Do the same for exercises B and C.
> - Alternate arm between each series, i.e.:  Do the first series of exercise A with the left arm. Then, do the first series of exercise A
>     with the right arm. Then, do the second series of exercise A with the
>     left arm. Then, do second first series of exercise A with the right
>     arm. Do the same for exercises B and C.

Comment: I'm sort of in agreement that this isn't opinion based. It might be really wonkish and irrelevant in the grand scheme of things but that doesn't make it primarily opinion based. There's rest cycles, ATP recharging, blood flow, etc that would make this at least approachable from an empirical standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Primarily Opinion Based answers are answers that lack evidence to prove **or** disprove their validity.  In your example, “*saying all strategies are pretty much the same* “ (which I did **not** say, or, imply - your assumption) is the equivalent of offering an opinion because, it too, lacks evidence.  That's not to say that future research may definitively answer your question.  It simply means that any reply you get will be based on the opinion of the person supplying the answer.  What worked for them, may **not** work for you.

In addition, the context of your original question lacked an understanding of how muscle growth is achieved.  As I stated in my comment, there are many factors that affect the ability to achieve muscle growth.  The suggestion that performing a specific exercise sequence without proper nutrition, rest, etc. can lead to muscular growth is incorrect.  And, in fact, in the sole response you received, **JJosaur later indicated he knew he was providing an opinion based response.**

In the end, it's entirely up to you to accept an opinion based response.  However, I would caution you against that for the simple reason that the answer is typically a guess, or, based on anecdotal evidence that may or may not be valid.

Comment: 1. "the context of your original question lacked an understanding of how muscle growth is achieved" -> I disagree, I was simply focusing on one aspect.

Comment: 2. "Primarily Opinion Based answers are answers that lack evidence to prove or disprove their validity. In your example, “ -> I disagree, one could simply answer that the scientific literature does not contain any answer and therefore we currently do not know. There is not opinion present in such an answer.

Comment: I'd also like to add that it takes more than my vote to put your question on hold. Obviously, there were others that agreed.

Comment: I can only see that one more who agreed. The two other ones might have voted something else (I don't have access to that information). And who knows how many disagreed. Regardless of the others, don't you agree with my two comments above?

Comment: No, I do not agree with you.

Comment: So can you explain which point(s) in my comments you disagree with?

Comment: If you want to discuss this ad infinitum, please take it to chat.

Answer (score 1):

Reopened question as I've added sources per request -- not sure how else to open this other than adding a new reply.

Comment: Unfortunately, only users with some amount of reputation may cast reopen votes.

Comment: #1 on this list just don't know how to do it (https://stackexchange.com/leagues/97/week/fitness/2017-06-11/24836#24836)

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer here for sure.

**LIFT #1**

- Let’s say you're doing 10 reps with just your (R) arm then 10 with
  your (L).

This results in 2 things:

1. A unilateral force causing destabilization (essentially causing you
   to laterally flex away from the arm that's lifting). The more unstable the less you’re able to lift.
   When alternating arms the destabilizing force would be reduced due
      to the counter weight of the dumbbell you're holding in your other
      hand
2. Assuming your using the proper weight to attain hypertrophy. Volume load (VL) would be lower lifting all sets on one side right or left it doesn’t matter as  you'd since you'd fatigue faster.

Unilateral Reps << Alternating Reps

---

The application of Physiological (glycogen depletion) and Biomechanical principles (stabilities relation to force) explain this:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5388079/ 
https://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/11537690-000000000-00000 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15320684

Comment: Unsure why you have been upvoted here, Meta is to talk about the SE Meta aspects of the question/answers. As such, this answer is not in the right place. If you think you have a authoritative and scientifically-backed answer to give then vote to reopen.

Comment: I've added related research to my post.